# #GRAILS Filtro de busca gsp não passando parametros para controller

Tags: groovy, grails

Tenho um formulario em uma página gsp e esse formulário tem um g:textField que o usuário vai digitar valores e depois clicar em um botão para filtrar os valores da grid.

Por exemplo: tem 3 registros na grid... Joaozinho, Jose, Maria. Se o usuário digitar Joaozinho e clicar em enviar, deverá aparecer apenas os resultados equivalentes a Joaozinho.

Meu formulário está caindo na controller, porém não está funcionando. Estou usando namedQuery na classe domain e acredito que estou passando parametros de forma errada.

Código do meu formulário:

```
<g:form url="[action:'searchByFilter']" method="GET">
                    <p>Filtro de busca</p>
                    <g:textField name="search" params="[search : search]"/>
                    <g:submitButton name="search" class="input-search" 
                    value="${message(code: 'default.button.search.filter')}" />
</g:form>
```

Código da minha classe Domain:

```
static namedQueries = {

    getInvoicesByFilter {
       eq 'description', 'search'
    }
}
```

O atributo search, é referente ao valor que foi digitado no input do formulário.

Código da controller:

```
def searchByFilter(Invoice invoiceInstance){
   respond Invoice.getInvoicesByFilter.list(params), view: "index"
}
```

Quando clico no botão de buscar do formulário, não está retornando nenhum valor, mas deveria trazer, pois tenho o registro no banco.

Oque devo fazer para corrigir este problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola.

Em seu controlador voce esta usando uma instance Invoice que nao esta usando em seu form.

```
def searchByFilter(){
   respond Invoice.getInvoicesByFilter.list(params), view: "index"
}
```

E em sua pagina tente fazer  o teste

```
<g:form url="[action:'searchByFilter']" method="GET">
                    <p>Filtro de busca</p>
                    <g:textField name="search"/>
                    <g:submitButton name="searchButton" class="input-search" 
                    value="${message(code: 'default.button.search.filter')}" />
</g:form>
```

Assim voce nao possui nomes duplicados em sua pagina.

Agora se este search for consultar apenas pelo nome  que voce ira pesquisar no campo Description

```
def searchByFilter(Invoice invoiceInstance){
   respond Invoice.findAllByDescription(params.search), view: "index"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você não enviar para a `namedQued` o atributo `search` ele vai  tentar filtrar pela string `search`.

```
getInvoicesByFilter { String search ->       
  eq 'description', search
}
```

Acho que seria algo do tipo, e para chamar:

```
def pubs = Invoice.getInvoicesByFilter(params.search).list()
```